# Use of undeclared identifier: Area and Perimeter of a Rectangle

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i am new to Objective-C, not entirely sure where I am going wrong here.
I am trying to get the program to print the area and perimeter of a square.
The program is telling me that I am sending an undeclared identifier to the perimeter and area methods

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Rectangle : NSObject
{
int width;
int height;
}

-(void) setWidth: (int) w;
-(void) setHeight: (int) h;
-(int) width;
-(int) height;
-(int) area;
-(int) perimeter;

@end

@implementation Rectangle


-(void) setWidth:(int)w   
{
width = w;
}

-(void) setHeight: (int)h
{
height = h;
}

-(int) width
{
return width;
}

-(int) height
{
return height;
}

-(int) area
{
return width*height;
}

-(int) perimeter
{
return (2*width + 2*height);
}


@end
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    Rectangle *rect1 = [[Rectangle alloc] init];

    [rect1 setWidth:2];
    [rect1 setHeight:7];

    NSLog(@"The perimeter of rect1 is: %i and the area is: %i", area, area);


}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no variable named area, it is a method. Try `[rect1 area];` and `[rect1 perimeter];`, you already created the object and used two methods correctly, you slipped on the area :( Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, what learning resources are you using?

I highly recommend Paul Hegarty's iOS dev course from Stanford. All free, and it really guides you through everything (ObjC syntax; iOS SDK etc.)

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Comment: I am using Programming in Objective C by Stephen G. Kochan. Thank you for the link, will look into it

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line to:

```
NSLog(@"The perimeter of rect1 is: %i and the area is: %i", [rect1 area], [rect1 perimeter]);
```

and it gave me the right results, thanks for the help!